# Does the following sum converge?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Is this sufficient to conclude that the sequence 
$n \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left\lvert u(x) \right\rvert e^{- \left\lvert x-n \right\rvert} dx$ is square-summable, i.e.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left\lvert u(x) \right\rvert e^{- \left\lvert x-n \right\rvert} dx \right)^2 < \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

By Hölder we have
$$\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb R}|u(x)|e^{-|x-n|}dx\right)^2\leq \left(\int\limits_{\mathbb R}|u(x)|^2 e^{-|x-n|}dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x-n|}dx\right)\leq 2\int\limits_{\mathbb R}|u(x)|^2 e^{-|x-n|}dx.$$
Now
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_{\mathbb R}|u(x)|^2 e^{-|x-n|}dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int\limits_{k}^{k+1}|u(x)|^2 e^{-|x-n|}dx\\
&\lesssim\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}e^{-|k-n|}\int\limits_{k}^{k+1}|u(x)|^2 dx\\
& =\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int\limits_{k}^{k+1}|u(x)|^2 dx\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-|k-n|}\\
&\lesssim\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int\limits_{k}^{k+1}|u(x)|^2 dx\\
&=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2
\end{align}
where the two $\lesssim$ (i.e. inequality up to a constant) are true because
$$e^{-|x-n|}\leq e^{-|k-n|+1}\quad\text{for}\quad x\in [k,k+1]$$
and for any $k$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-|k-n|}<\sum_{l\in\mathbb Z} e^{-|l|}<2\sum_{l=0}^\infty e^{-l}=2\frac{e}{e-1}.$$

Comment: I feel like there must be a more general argument, since the sum in the question is $\sum_n (u*g)(n)^2$, where $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$, and if $u*g$ does not oscillate much this sum is roughly $\int |u*g|^2\leq \|u\|_2^2\|g\|_1^2$ by Young's inequality.